# scrubbing with netfilter

Tags: iptables

It exist a solution on packetfilter for doing scrub.
I search the same thing on netfilter.

("Scrubbing" is the normalization of packets so there are no ambiguities in interpretation by the ultimate destination of the packet. The scrub directive also reassembles fragmented packets, protecting some operating systems from some forms of attack, and drops TCP packets that have invalid flag combinations.).

Exist it an equivalent solution on netfilter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No exact equivalent of `scrub` from BSD's packetfilter (`pf`) exists in Linux's netfilter (`iptables`). However, much of what `pf`'s `scrub` can do can also be done with `iptables`, with the notable exceptions of some `fragment` operations (`crop` and `reassemble`) and stateful TCP connection normalizations (`reassemble tcp`).

Comment: it don't exist an equivalent of the bsd's command "scrub in all" on iptables?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Ok, and nothing can do a similar thing or a part of this? On what correspond the option -f (fragment) on netfilter?